# Is there a way where I can reduce the time taken to install my apk file into the emulator?

Tags: android, ant

My apk size is around 35mb. As of now it takes around 5 mins to get loaded. If I install it using ant script, it takes around 7-10 mins.

Comment: can you just says acject size of your res folder?

Comment: size of the apk file is 35MB

Answer (score 0):

Try test it on your phone, with AirDroid, you can copy the APK from your browser in no time to your device via wifi.

The apk file is in the bin folder of your project after you run it.

Comment: That is what we currently follow.
But the scenario is that, we are trying to install into the emulator as a part of testing automatically. So emulator launch and app installation happens with the help of the script.